# Node.js v10.20.1::> Sequelize findOne speed is too slow

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

**1. Sequelize Config**

```
import { Sequelize, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    'test', 
    'root', 
    process.env.DB_PASSWORD, 
    {
        host: 'localhost',
        dialect: 'mysql', 
        define: {
            timestamps: false,
        },
        logging: false,
        pool: {
            max: 10,
            min: 0,
            idle: 10000,
        },
    }
);

export function model(): any {
    return sequelize.define(
        'sample',
        {
            seq: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                primaryKey: true,
                allowNull: false,
            },
            data: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
            },
        },
        {
            indexes: [
                {
                    unique: false,
                    fields: ['seq'],
                },
            ],
        }
    );
}
```

**2. Select**

```
import 'dotenv/config';
import express from 'express';
import { model } from './database';
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get('/', async (_req, res) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        await model().create({ seq: i, data: String(i) });
    }
    res.send('done');
});

app.post('/', async (_req, res) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        await model().findOne({ where: { seq: i } });
    }
    res.send('done');
});

app.post('/text', async (_req, res) => {
    res.send('done');
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log('✔️  Express Server Started on', port));
```

> https://naptok.github.io/Node.js-Stress-Test

The code is select 10 rows in 1 time
And I did try 180 times in 1 minute

**Why this code is too slow?**

using 3300 ~ 5000ms for selecting one

Express echo only using 1 ~ 10ms

Is it Sequelize pool Issue?
I did increase pool max to 10 -> 20, but it doesn't ANSWER...

Please Help me..

Comment: Did you try to execute a result SQL from this sequelize query?

Comment: It takes 0 ~ 10ms in SQL

Comment: Try to add `raw: true` to options of findOne and estimate time again